# @Url.Action is null or "" in javascript when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this function located in a controller called AccountCodes.

```
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Process()
    {
        JsonResult result = new JsonResult(null);
        List<string> uploadResults = new List<string>();
        return Ok(uploadResults);
    }
```

My intention is to use dropzone to push files to this function. When I try to load the url in the razor view in a variable like this:

```
var url = "@Url.Action("Process", "AccountCodes",new { area="Configurations"})";
```

However, when I load the page and look at the console, the url is always "". Am I missing something?

EDIT:

This is where I put the javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = "@Url.Action("Process", "AccountCodes",new { area="Configurations"})";
    $("#reset").attr("disabled", true);
});
```

Comment: better show where are you put this javascript code

Comment: Yup I've placed it in my edit

Comment: var url = '@Url.Action("Process", "AccountCodes",new { area="Configurations"})', use single quote and try.

Comment: Its still null with quotes or no quotes. I also put it outside the document ready but its still blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct. It may because that you have some wrong global configuration.

Please verify the following things:

### Step 1: Check your application

Use MVC in your start up:

```cs
        // Startup.cs
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            // Other middlewares.
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        }
```

### Step 2: Check your controller

Make sure there is a controller named `AccountCodesController`.

Make sure `AccountCodesController` extends `Controller`.

Check your routes. If you specify `[Route("Something")]` to your controller, make sure it is absolutely correct.

### Step 3: Try adding a route to your action.

Adding an attribute `[Route('SomeAction')]` to your action `Process` might solves this.

### Step 4: Check your area existance

Please make sure your controller is located in correct area as this document mentioned: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-2.2#areas-for-controllers-with-views  .

```cs
namespace MVCareas.Areas.Products.Controllers
{
    [Area("Products")]
    public class ManageController : Controller
```

Comment: The strange part is that when I remove my Area, the url appears

Comment: Hi, I guess your project folder structure did not follow the correct area structure. Please reference this document and check your area configuration: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-2.2#area-folder-structure